# What is the sum in 37th bracket....?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a series like this

$$\left(7^0\right)+\left(7+7^2+7^3\right)+\left(7^4+7^5+...+7^8\right)+\left(7^9+7^{10}+...+7^{15}\right)$$

I want to find the sum in the 37th bracket.Can anyone guys help?

I got the clue like in the 2nd bracket there are 3 terms and in the third bracket there are 5 terms but i am unable to get the exact output..

Comment: Hint: relate the exponent of the first term of the $n$-th bracket with $n$ (for simplicity, consider the $(1)$ to be the $0$-th bracket).

Comment: please explain in detail  Alberto Debernardi

Comment: What is the exponent that the number $7$ has in the first occurrence of each bracket?

Comment: It seems to me that this sum can be expressed like so $$S_n = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} \sum_{p = 1}^{2k-1}7^{(k-1)^2 + p - 1} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}7^{(k-1)^2}\sum_{p=1}^{2k-1}7^{p-1}$$ which can be further developed

Comment: But if just the bracket number $n$ is required then it's value is $7^{(n-1)^2}\sum_{p=0}^{2n-2}7^{p} = 7^{(n-1)^2} \frac{1 - 7^{2*n - 1}}{1 - 7}$. Take n = 37

Answer (score 1):

Your $37^{th}$ term will be this

$S=(7^{36^2} + 7^{36^2 +1}+.....+7^{37^2-1})$;

$S=7^{36^2}(7^0 + 7^1 +.....+7^{2(36)})$

$S=7^{36^2}(\frac{7^{2(36) +1}-1}{7-1})$

Answer (score 0):

There are $2n-1$ terms in the $n$th bracket. Therefore, the last exponent in the $36$th bracket will be

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{36}(2n-1) - 1=2\sum_{n=1}^{36}n-\sum_{n=1}^{36}1 - 1= 2\frac{36\cdot 37}{2} - 36 - 1=36^{2} - 1.
$$

Thus, the first term in the $37$th bracket is $7^{36^{2}}$ and the last term is $7^{36^{2}+2n-2}$.